# Can't resize my original 500gb mac disk

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, disk-space

I previously created a partition for Asahi Linux of 200gb or so, then I deleted it with the following command:

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s5
```

Then, to resize the original disk to its 500gb I tried:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

but it doesn't work:

```
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

This is the current state of my mac:
[image]

```
diskutil list
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Post to your question the output from the command `diskutil list`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson done

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it, I just had to erase disk0s4